# clBLAS (OpenCL) matrix inversion

Tags: matrix, opencl, inversion

is it possible to calculate a general matrix inversion using clBLAS?
Or point me to an example kernel?
The matrices to invert will be fairly small (typically 7*7, 28*28 or 84*84), but the inversion will only be a part of larger algorithm, so it still should be done on gpu.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943618/matrix-inversion-in-opencl

Comment: I have read that and considered it very old. Moreover, I don't have those books. Possibly someone has online example?